# How to work with gtfs real time in OpenTripPlanner

Tags: python, gtfs, opentripplanner

I am working with opentripplanner to show trips and stops and I can work fine with GTFS. Now, I want to work with GTFS Real Time, but I don't know how to generate pb files. What are the first steps to work with GTFS Real Time?

Comment: GTFS realtime is based on protocol buffers - have you looked at the Google Developers introduction - https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/

Answer (score 0):

OpenTripPlanner consumes GTFS-RT feeds. Usually, these realtime feeds are generated by the transit agencies and you can just create a realtime updater in the OTP config. See this entry in the docs: http://docs.opentripplanner.org/en/latest/Configuration/#real-time-data

Comment: OK, but can you help me with How can I create and consume realtime feeds. I have already created a realtime updater in the OTP config, but I don't know how it works.

Comment: I'd recommend sending an email to the OpenTripPlanner google group: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/opentripplanner-users  Be sure to include all relevant details about your current config and the commands you are executing.